# Java Swing Application for specifying the size of frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am making an application where am using some Jframes, couple of buttons .

But the problem is I am using jframe.setsize(1366,786) for specifying the size of frame , what if i will use this software in a maching with large wide screen monitor . Suppose 1600*900 .

How can i specify to occupy the complete screen by jframe??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to get width & height of window then try this:

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
int scrHeight = screenSize.height ;
int scrWidth = screenSize.width ;
```

Comment: and then put these values as setsize(scrhight, scrwidth)??

Answer (score 3):

Your can open it maximized by using `setExtendedState`.

```
setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

You can look at the JavaDoc for more info http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html

Comment: I think there is a significant difference between "maximizing a frame" and "making a frame as large as the screen". Being maximized is a *state* of the frame. You can de-maximize it and then it will have an arbitrary size again. But Suzon showed how to make the frame as large as the screen in http://stackoverflow.com/a/22513990

Answer (score 0):

`frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);`